# A set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is co-$\mathcal{W},$ if $\mathbb{R}-X$ has property $\mathcal{W}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification, problem-solving

This is a problem from *Proofs and Fundamentals* by Ethan D. Bloch (Problem $3.4.7$).

Suppose that $\mathcal{W}$ is some property of subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$ A subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is $\text{co-}\mathcal{W},$ if $\mathbb{R}-X$ has property $\mathcal{W}.$ Let $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of $\text{co-}\mathcal{W}$ subsets of $\mathbb{R},$ where $I$ is some indexing set.

I am asked to either prove that $\bigcup_{i \in I}X_i$ is $\text{co-}\mathcal{W},$ or give a counterexample for the following case.

1. A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has property $\mathcal{W}$ if and only if it is finite.

**My attempt:** Let’s first see what kind of subsets have the property $\mathcal{W}.$ It is required that these subsets are finite. It can’t be any interval of $\mathbb{R},$ if it was, then it would be infinite.

If we have a set of $n$ real numbers, that set would be finite.

So a finite set on $\mathbb{R}$ is a set of the form $X = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n\}$ for some non-negative integer $n,$ where each $a_i$ is a real number, for all $i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}.$

By definition, $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is $\text{co-}
\mathcal{W},$ if $\mathbb{R}-X$ has property $\mathcal{W}.$ So, in order to have a set $X$ that is $\text{co-}\mathcal{W},$ we require $\mathbb{R}-X$ to be finite.

> For example, if $X = (-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty),$ then $\mathbb{R}-X=\{0\}.$ So $X$ is $\text{co-}\mathcal{W}.$ Note that $X$ is infinite. So the union of $\text{co-}\mathcal{W}$ subsets will be infinite. From here how can I determine, that this union is or is not $\text{co-}\mathcal{W}?$

For the next exercise, we have the case that

2. A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\text{co-}\mathcal{W}$ if and only if it has at most $7$ elements. But for this one, I have no idea how to solve it.

Can someone please help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I changed multiple occurences of $\text{co}-\mathcal W$ in this question to $\text{co-}\mathcal W.$ I see this from time to time on m.s.e., when people write things like $\text{“}\sigma-\text{algebra”}$ instead of $\text{“}\sigma\text{-algebra”},$ and I have long wondered: Do people who write things like that simply not notice this distinction? Or do they think $\text{“}\sigma-\text{algebra”}$ rather than $\text{“}\sigma\text{-algebra”},$ is appropiate? Or do they think MathJax is not up to the task of doing it right? Or what? $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Any union of cofinite sets is cofinite: Let $X_i \subset \mathbb{R}$ be cofinite with $Y_i := \mathbb{R} \setminus X_i$ finite. Then $\bigcap_{i \in I} Y_i$ is also finite and hence $\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i = \mathbb{R} \setminus \bigcap_{i \in I} Y_i$ is cofinite.
2. Let co-$\mathcal{W}$ be the property of having at most $7$ elements. Then a union of co-$\mathcal{W}$ sets is not necessarily co-$\mathcal{W}$. To see this take $X_1= \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 \}$ and $X_2=\{11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 \}$. Then $|X_1 \cup X_2| = 14$ and so the union is not co-$\mathcal{W}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Sorry for answering just now. Although I don’t really see why you conclude that $\bigcap _{i \in I} Y_i$ is also finite?

Comment: Intersection of finite sets is finite, this should be clear.